# trying to learn objective-c delegates. why wont my sample project work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, ios6, delegates

I am trying to pass data between two view controllers.  viewcontroller2 is a delegate of viewcontroller..   note.. i called the delegate property "homie"  yes I know this is bad practice but I am just messing around trying to understand the concept.

here is viewcontroller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)sendData:(NSString *)theString;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ViewControllerDelegate> homie;
- (void)doSomething;
- (IBAction)doneText:(id)sender;

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)doSomething{
}

- (IBAction)doneText:(id)sender {
    UITextField *thisField = sender;

    if([_homie respondsToSelector:@selector(sendData:)]){
        [_homie sendData:[thisField text]];
    }
}
```

now here is the other view controller implementing the first

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController <ViewControllerDelegate>

- (IBAction)hittingbtn:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *vc;

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ViewController *theview = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    theview.homie = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// DELEGATE METHOD
- (void)sendData:(NSString *)theString{
    [_textfield setText:theString];
}

- (IBAction)hittingbtn:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

in viewdidload I instantiate the first viewcontroller, and set myself as its delegate.  im assuming then when that viewcontroller2 runs the code in its method then it will see if its delegate has implemented the delegate method and use that code..  what am i missing here?

Comment: Can you debug the `sendData:` method to see if it's being called? Either by placing a breakpoint, or inserting an `NSLog()` statement?

Comment: it is not being called

Comment: I think the problem is that your alloc init of ViewController is creating a different instance from the one you have on screen. How are you putting ViewController on screen?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by "put on screen" rdelmar.  I just created a viewcontroller in storyboard.  and then i added a UIViewController class file to the project.  then i assigned the viewcontroller in the storyboard to my class file.  each view has a button that creates a modal segue between the two.  does that answer your question?

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that there is *absolutely* nothing special about a "delegate" -- it's just another class that you may pass to some API.  Though there are "patterns" that are "usual" and have been found to be most convenient in many cases, there is no particular scheme you must follow.  (But as with any other class, a class used to create delegates can have multiple instances, and you can't have your data in one instance and expect that data to be observable in another instance of the class.)

Comment: well that makes sense.  I figure the problem is with the fact i am instantiating that viewcontroller again.  it's not really acting on whats originally created.  but it would be great if someone could guide me on how to reference the original view controller rather than a instantiation that i create.

Comment: That last topic is probably second only to DateFormatter questions in SO dupes for Objective-C.  Search for "passing data between view controllers" in the "search" box at the upper right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you use ViewControllers wrong. You have initialized ViewController

```
ViewController *theview = [[ViewController alloc]init];
theview.homie = self;
```

And what next? You haven't assign it to your properties or something. What have you do? It's simple. You have to implement `- (void)prepareForSegue:sender:`. First of all in your storyboard set segue's identifier. Then do following.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        ViewController *destinationViewController = (ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        ViewController.homie = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this necessary in order to use delegation between two view controllers?

Comment: `- (void)prepareForSegue:sender`? No. Having destination view controller instance? Yes.

Comment: @hamobi just try my code, it will work. It's really simple and clear, in a few weeks you'll understand it well. Delegation is main Objective-C feature, in my opinion, so try to use it.

Comment: your code isnt working for me.  I am assuming that we are sending our first view controller to the second, and setting that as the delegate in the second view controller.  I implement this in the first view controller using the segue "toTwo"  and i do hit my breakpoint..  

this line of code gives me a syntax error though
"ViewController.homie = self;"   I can't make that assignment

Comment: As I understood your segue looks so: ViewController2 -- modal segue --> ViewController.`- (void)prepareForSegue:sender` has to be implemented in ViewController2.

Comment: ok i got it.. my delegate method is being called.  i think i can work the rest out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delegate in prepareForSegue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setHomie)]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setHomie:self];
    //or
    if ([[segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]) {
        ViewController *destinationViewController = (ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        ViewController.homie = self;
    }
    //or the segue identifier which has already been mentioned
}
```